# The use of "to" after "arrive"

Tags: prepositions

It [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zs6yVfJ3qcY) video (during minute 1:50 and then 7:10) you can hear:

> We've just arrived **to** the Shetland Islands.
>
> We have just arrived **to** St Ninian's Isle.

I've always thought that only 2 prepositions can be used after *arrive* - either *at* or *in*: We arrived *at* the hotel.  I should arrive *in* London tomorrow morning.

So, what would *to* after *arrive* be - just bad grammar? Or could it be something regional?

Comment: Yes it's wrong. It probably comes from a non native English speaker or possibly someone who was going to say something else, such as **coming to** .

Comment: @RonaldSole I thought so too, but this YouTuber seems to be a native speaker, and he makes the same mistake more than once. I think we can put it down to bad grammar. This only proves that even native speakers are not perfect speakers.

Comment: I've yet to meet an English speaker who doesn't admit to sometimes getting it wrong - starting with myself.

Comment: It's certainly not idiomatic, but I can find no reason to call it flat-out ungrammatical in terms of syntax. (And speech very often isn't precise anyway.)